# xslt: preserve space that exist in xslt without adding xsl:text

Tags: xslt, formatting, whitespace

my xml

```
<user>
 <name>John</name>
 <surname>Doe</surname>
</user>
```

my xslt

```
<xsl:template match="user">
 <xsl:value-of select="name"/> <xsl:value-of select="surname"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to preserve the space between the two "value-of" = 
I want the output to be `John Doe` and not `JohnDoe`.

Can I do it without adding 
`<xsl:text> </xsl:text>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xml:space="preserve"` on any containing element (`xsl:template` here) although then you'd also get the newlines and spaces from the start and end of the template.

Comment: How can I preserve only single space when it having the in-between the tags 
  <name>John</name>
 <surname>Doe</surname>

Comment: @Narasimha use `xml:space` on a parent or `<name>John</name><xsl:text> </xsl:text><surname>Doe</surname>`

Comment: in my case input file will come like below  ...above solution will not work                                                        
<Name>
<FirstName>A</FirstName> <LastName>B</LastName>
</Name>

Output :: A B

<Name>
<FirstName>A</FirstName><LastName>B</LastName>
</Name>

Output :: AB

Comment: don't ask questions on comments on old answers ask a new question with a real example in a code block. Impossible to guess your issue from such a fragment

Comment: I added new question ...link in below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74686563/how-to-preserve-the-space-between-the-xml-node-using-xslt