# How to preserve the space between the xml node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want preserve the space between the xml node using xslt when space available in nodes and when space is not available in between the tags its not required.

```
    <Name>
      <FirstName>A</FirstName> <LastName>B</LastName>
    </Name>
    
    Expected Output :: A B

    <Name>
      <FirstName>A</FirstName><LastName>B</LastName>
    </Name>
    
    Expected Output :: AB
```

Answer (score 0):

It's surprisingly tricky, because you want to preserve the text nodes between `FirstName` and `LastName`, but to drop the text nodes before `FirstName` and after `LastName`. I think I would do

```
replace(string(Name), '^\s+|\s+$', '')
```

You also need to make sure that the whitespace isn't dropped earlier: don't use `xsl:strip-space` in the stylesheet, and if you're using a Microsoft XML parser, make sure it is configured to retain whitespace between elements.